# ParcelFileDescriptor возвращает не валидный FileDescriptor

Tags: java, android

Получаю ParcelFileDecriptor таким образом ParcelFileDescriptor.fromSocket(socket) чтобы потом передать через AIDL в другой процесс. Но иногда он мне возвращает не валидный где FileDescriptor равен -1. И когда я пытаюсь передать через AIDL то получаю крэш. Почему такое происходит?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Возможно, в работе уже есть какой-то объект? В документации написано так:
ParcelFileDescriptor fromSocket (Socket socket)

> Create a new ParcelFileDescriptor from the specified Socket. The new
>   ParcelFileDescriptor holds a dup of the original FileDescriptor in the
>   Socket, so you must still close the Socket as well as the new
>   ParcelFileDescriptor.